# What is the difference between these two notions of basis for a topology?

Tags: general-topology, definition, intuition

From *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by John M. Lee:

> [image]
>
> [image]

---

**If we have collection of subsets of some set $X$, why do we need to check that it satisfies the two conditions in the proposition? Is it not enough to check that it satisfies the definition of *basis for the topology of $X$*?**

I see that in the definition we start with a topological space $X$, whereas in the proposition we just start from the set $X$, but I cannot tell exactly what the difference is.

---

---

---

---

For this exercise:[image]

do I want to show that it satisfies the definition above, or that it satisfies the proposition?

Comment: You have it right: The definition of "basis" assumes that $X$ is a topological space (so $X$ already has a topology).  But in the proposition, $X$ is just a set.  The point is that the proposition *creates* a topology on $X$ *such that* the given collection $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for that topology.  For the exercise, you have to check (i) and (ii) in the proposition. Doing so lets you conclude that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some (unique) topology on $X_1 \times \cdots \times X_n$.  That topology is then *called* the "product topology."

Comment: In some cases, it might be easier to check the conditions of the proposition than to check the conditions of the definition directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two situations that must be discerned:

1) $X$ is some topological space so a topology $\tau_X\subseteq\wp(X)$ is fixed. Then we can have bases for this specific topology. These are collections $\mathcal B$ that satisfy the conditions (i) and (ii) that are mentioned in the definition above.

2) There is a set $X$ but not yet a fixed topology on it. Then we can wonder: what are the characteristics of a collection $\mathcal B$ that can serve as a basis of some topology? These characteristics are mentioned in (i) and (ii) in the proposition below.

If it is *known* already that $\mathcal B$ indeed serves as a basis of some topology then you do not have to check anymore whether the collection satisfies the conditions mentioned in the proposition. That will automatically be the case.

Comment: Good clarification. I am still confused about the last sentence in the proposition which deals with uniqueness. Is it saying that if we have another topology on $X$ for which $\mathcal  B$ is a basis, then in actuality, both topologies are the same? Can you clarify on this because it seems to me that this would be obviously so. If we have another topology which is derived from the same collection $\mathcal B$, how would we possibly arrive at some other topology?

Comment: It is saying the the topology for which $\mathcal B$ serves as a basis is completely determined by $\mathcal B$. So it can only be the basis on exactly one topology. Conversely it is not excluded that a topology has more than one basis.

Comment: So, $\tau_1$ is a topology on $X$ where $\mathcal B$ is a basis, and $\tau_2$ is another topology on $X$ where $\mathcal B$ is also a basis, then it must be that $\tau_1=\tau_2$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In fact the topology of which $\mathcal B$ serves as basis is the collection of sets that can be written as a union of sets that belong to $\mathcal B$.

Comment: Well done, good and faithful servant!

Comment: Glad to help. I indeed love those words.

Answer (score 1):

You need condition (i) to prove that $X$ is an open set.

You need condition (ii) to prove that the intersection of two basis elements is an open set.